# How do I parse XML message payload in spring?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I'm using spring integration to get messages off of an outgoing channel.  Each message is in the following format:

```
<message>
  <properties>
    <property>
      <key>a</key>
      <value>b</value>
    </property>
    <property>
      <key>c</key>
      <value>d</value>
    </property>
  </properties>
</message>
```

For each message I want to parse value b for key a and write to disk.  How can I do this in spring integration?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Java: How to read and write xml files?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7373567/java-how-to-read-and-write-xml-files)

Comment: Thanks,  how would I do this in spring integration?

Comment: How about this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556624/xml-deserialization-to-pojo-using-jackson-xmlmapper

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is [XpathSplitter](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html#xml-xpath-splitting) to perform some `xpath` against incoming document and produce sub-documents for matched parts.

There is just regular [XPathTransformer](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/xml.html#xml-xpath-transformer) to extract the part of incoming document according provided `xpath`.

To store to disk you should use [FileWritingMessageHandler](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/4.3.2.RELEASE/reference/html/files.html#file-writing).

It's really isn't clear why that **Reference Manual** isn't enough to find an answer...

Comment: I ended up using an XPathTransformer with an XPathExpression.

Answer (score 0):

You can use **UnmarshallingTransformer** from Spring Integration, refer this official  [documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/xml.html#xml-unmarshalling-transformer).

> An **UnmarshallingTransformer** allows an **XML Source** to be unmarshalled
>   using implementations of the Spring OXM Unmarshaller. Spring’s
>   Object/XML Mapping support provides several implementations supporting
>   marshalling and unmarshalling using JAXB, Castor and JiBX amongst
>   others. The unmarshaller requires an instance of Source. If the
>   message payload is not an instance of Source, conversion will be
>   attempted. Currently String, File and org.w3c.dom.Document payloads
>   are supported. Custom conversion to a Source is also supported by
>   injecting an implementation of a SourceFactory.