# Converting XML String to Java Object Jackson / JAXB

Tags: java, xml, jackson, jaxb, jackson-databind

First time posting on stackoverflow other than looking for some help!

I've got a blob of XML that I am trying to deserialize into a simple Java Object.

I have the following blob of XML:

```
<library>
    <book index="654" name="Harry Potter" price="£11.99" rating="5"/>
    <book index="7893" name="Ready Player One" price="£16.99" rating="5"/>
    <book index="433" name="Piers Morgan; Don't You Know Who I Am?" price="£8.99" rating="2"/>
</library>
```

I am then trying to convert that into a simple POJO:

```
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "library")
public class Library {
    //This will be the breaking point :'(
    List<Book> bookList = new ArrayList<>();
}

public class Book {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    Integer index;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    String name;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    String price;

    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    Integer rating;
}
```

I am struggling to find the right annotations to use in Jacksons documentation. I'm sure this must be a really simple change, as it normally is!

I opted for Jackson over JAXB as Jackson is newer library, and I'm aware of some speed issues associated with JAXB.

No matter how hard I try here I keep getting stuck the books list is coming back with no entries. Can anyone help? Would anyone recommend I take a look at JAXB over Jackson?

Comment: try this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25556624/xml-deserialization-to-pojo-using-jackson-xmlmapper - BTW: JAXB is not that bad and it is not slow if used properly. Newer does not mean better...

Comment: That would work if I was dealing with properties of an XML document, but I'm only dealing with attributes here in a tag. I'll give the above a go.

Comment: There are no such things as "properties" of XML document. There are only elements and attributes of elements. Both of them translate to POJO as properties regardless by JAXB, Jackson or anything else. Read given link more closely... You have to define your POJO `List<Book> bookList` property as element of the Root Element - `library` in your case.

Answer (score 3):

As you expected, you only need some annotations on your `List<Book>` property,
to make the Jackson deserialization work correctly with your XML contents:

- You need [`@JacksonXmlProperty`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.4.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlProperty.html) with `isAttribute = false`
  (to tell Jackson you have `<book>`elements, but not `book = "...."` attributes)
  and `localName = "book"` (to tell Jackson the name of these elements)
- You need [`@JacksonXmlElementWrapper`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-dataformat-xml/javadoc/2.4.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/dataformat/xml/annotation/JacksonXmlElementWrapper.html) with `useWrapping = false`
  (to tell Jackson you don't have an additional wrapper element around these `<book>` elements)
- And by the way: You don't need to initialize it with `= new ArrayList<>()`, because
  the Jackson deserialization will care for that, too.

```
@JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = false, localName = "book")
@JacksonXmlElementWrapper(useWrapping = false)
List<Book> bookList;
```